# Copy file to remote Windows server in pipeline using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, remote-desktop, file-copying

I have tried multiple solutions in jenkins to copy a file on remote which is EC2 window server on AWS.

1. Publish over ssh: provided key, hostname, username and password but connection is failed every time
2. pipeline script:

   pipeline {
   agent any

   ```
        stages {
            stage('SCP') {
                steps {
                    bat '"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\scp.exe" -i "C:\\Live" C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local\\Jenkins\\.jenkins\\workspace\\MSDeploy\\abc.txt abc.txt'
                    bat '"c:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\ssh.exe" -i "C:\\Live" tom@xy.xyz.xy.xz ls -ltr'
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   where `C:\Live` is remote server directory and `C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local\\Jenkins\\.jenkins\\workspace\\MSDeploy\\abc.txt` is the local directory, but it throws an error: shows no such file or directory found

3. ```
   pipeline {
    agent any
    stage ('Deploy') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'var', credentialsId: 'credid', secretKeyVariable: 'seckey']]) {
                writeFile file: 'groovy1.txt', text: 'ls'
                bat 'ls -l groovy1.txt'
                bat 'cat groovy1.txt'
            }
        } 
    }
   }
   ```

It does create file with text but doesn't work. None of the solutions worked for me.

What I have missed?

Comment: It's marked as may not be safe to use (and up for adoption), but have you looked at [publish over cifs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-cifs)? It is the cousin to [publish over ssh](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

You're using windows server, you need to use some tools to achieve this, copy over ssh probably won't work here. The best straight solution which I normally use it.

Step 1:

1. Create a network drive and attached it with shared folder.
2. You can use bat command to attach

> ```
> net use N: \\ServerName\Folder /user:Administrator Password
> ```

N is your drive

3. Now from jenkins use the copy command.

> copy "D:\Jenkins\file N:"

You can use these commands in your jenkins file refer this link for the same
https://thenucleargeeks.com/2020/11/24/how-to-run-batch-scripts-commands-in-jenkinsfile/
This will work for your case, let me know if you face any issue.